# How do I make a loop cut parallel to an external loop?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, looping

I have a mesh and want to create a loop cut between loops 1 and 2, but it should be parallel to the top loop. Sorry if I'm not explaining it clearly, I am hoping someone more experienced with Blender could help. Thanks in advance :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: The between edge will work as a loop cut, why you are trying to overwrite a different loop cut on it :/

Comment: Appreciate the response :) I'm not quite sure what you mean by the between edge, but I'm trying to avoid moving an existing loop so to maintain the even curvature of the mesh.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. If you could tell what you're trying to model and post some reference images, maybe someone could help. Or drawing roughly what you want on the image with paint or photoshop would be great.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment, I was a bit brain dead from trying to work this out when I posted. What I'm looking to do, is create a loop cut between loops 1 and 2, but have it parallel to the top loop, without moving any existing loops.

Comment: Hi. If you need to add more information or clarify what you meant, you should add this information/remove unnecessary information to/from the question itself instead of redirecting people to the comments.

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed now!